# Is $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G = \mathbb{Z}_{36}$. Is $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$ ?

---

$\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ iff $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

Don't I just try breaking it down until it becomes $\mathbb{Z}_{6} \times \mathbb{Z}_6$? Rather, why can't I?

Comment: Since $6$ and $6$ are not coprime, the answer is no. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider the orders of the elements. In $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$, there is an element of order $36$. What are the possible orders of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_6$? (*Answer - not $36$*).

Answer (score 0):

No because in $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ there is only one subgroup of order $6$ because $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ is cyclic